# Is there a way to make __timeShift only select certain days of the week?

Tags: jmeter, performance-testing

The current function in use in the JMeter script is

```
${__timeShift(dd/MM/yyyy,${__time(dd/MM/yyyy)},-P31D,,)}
```

to specify a review date 31 days ago.

I now learn that the project requires the review date to always fall on a Monday. Is there any way to make sure that performing a timeShift only selects a Monday?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm afraid [__timeShift()](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html#__timeShift) function is not flexible enough, you can consider using [__groovy()](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html#__groovy) function instead and implement the following algorithm:

1. Get current date
2. Subtract 31 day
3. If current day of week is Monday - return the date in the past
4. Otherwise add 1 day until the date in the past becomes Monday

Example function code:

```
${__groovy(def now = new Date(); def monthAgo = now.minus(31); while (monthAgo[Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK] != Calendar.MONDAY) { monthAgo = monthAgo.plus(1)}; return monthAgo.format('dd/MM/yyyy'),)}
```

Demo:

[image]

More information: [Apache Groovy - Why and How You Should Use It](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/groovy-new-black/)

Comment: Thanks - shame I can't work this with timeShift, but this worked a dream!

Comment: Instead of the while loop, you coud use the `day` property of the date instance and calculate the next monday after 31 days:

Comment: Since comments can only be edited for five minutes, here is what I thought:

`${__groovy(def now = new Date(); return (now - now.day + 5 * 7).format('dd/MM/YYYY')}`

Calculate monday and add a number of weeks to get the 31 day offset.

Comment: If you're [this Felix Schumacher](https://github.com/FSchumacher) I'm starting thinking about becoming a JMeter contributor in order to be able to check your pull requests as the function neither "calculates Monday" nor returns the date in the past.

Comment: That's me and you are right, I should have read the question more careful about the direction of the timeshift and should not have forgotten to add the offset to get to the next monday and a correcting factor.

So the answer could then be `${__groovy(def now = new Date(); def c = now.day<=3?1:0; (now - (now.day + 6 + (c+3)*7)).format('dd/MM/YYYY'),)}`